# Why i cant detect accept cookies button on Badoo?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

hey have problem with accepting cookies on badoo.com

Im using Selenium + Java

Really thanks for help

Tried:

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"notice\"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/button[2]"));
element.click();
```

but that cant detect this button.